# Using #include "Stdafx.h" in cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was always thinking that I must include `#include "Stdafx.h"` line at very top of each header file in project like it is said in description. I have created simple MFC dialog based application with help of wizzard and found that header files not contains `#include "Stdafx.h"` lines, but cpp ones has them. So, when I must use `#include "Stdafx.h"` line in cpp and when in h one?

Comment: `stdafx.h` is for projects with precompiled headers. Use it when you desire precompiled headers.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: in a `.h`: never; in a `.cpp` if, and only if, it is configured with precompiled headers (they are by default).

The rationale is that `#include "stdafx.h"` is used to include the precompiled headers (built when compiling `stdafx.cpp`). In order for them to be effective they must be the very first line of the compilation unit (not counting blanks or comments). And that very first line cannot be in a header file because the `#include` that includes it comes first!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using #include "stdafx.h" in cpp files only, since you might want to compile one cpp 'with' precompiled headers, and another cpp 'without' precompiled headers.

Also, when you create projects using DevStudio's wizard, these stdafx.h includes will be located in the cpp files.